# Expanding a partition on an SD card with GParted fails

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

I copied a Raspberry PI System from an 8GB SD onto a 16GB SD using [ApplePi-Baker](http://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/raspberry-pi/macosx-apple-pi-baker/). Everything is working fine, except for the fact I'm missing 8GB in this setup. So I popped the card into a machine running Ubuntu and tried to change partitioning with GParted. But I must be doing something wrong, I can't resize partition /dev/sdb7. [Image of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng6mK.png)

The partition in question is not mounted, and there is plenty of free space. Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Comment: You would have to resize the Extended partition first before you could resize /dev/sdb7.

Comment: Aha, OK. That's the one with the key... how can I resize that? GParted wont let me.

Comment: /dev/sdb2 would have to be resized into the unallocated space.  That would create unallocated (free space) that you could then resize /dev/sdb7 into.

Comment: Sorry just found out what you meant, and edited my response... OK, so'I'll just have to unmount everything thats on there...

Comment: Everything on that would have to be unmounted.  Try right click each partition, starting with /dev/sdb7, then /dev/sdb6, then /dev/sdb5, then /dev/sdb2 and selecting unmount before trying to resize anything.

Comment: However, it doesn't look like /dev/sdb7 is mounted.  That is what the little keys mean is that they are mounted.  To avoid corruption or damage, once they are mounted, you cannot manipulate any of those partitions.

Comment: You're welcome!  Answer created.  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partitions with the keys next to them mean that they are `mounted` partitions and cannot be deleted, resized, moved, etc.

If you right click on each of those mounted partitions, starting with the partitions that are contained in the Extended partition `/dev/sdb2` and choose `Unmount`, you can then resize the Extended `/dev/sdb2` by filling in the Uncallocated space creating the free space inside the Extended partition allowing you to resize partition `/dev/sdb7` to use up the unallocated free space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Didn't see that connection there. Thanks tons!

Comment: @Sherlock70 You're very welcome!  Glad I was able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would suggest you to use disks application instead of gparted[image]

2.open the disks and select your sd card there and you will see options for partitioning of sd card from the point focused in image below[![][2]][2]

Comment: Oh, thats interesting! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob here. I have a 32GB microSD card. Formmatted it for a Odroid and put with dd an image on it. With:

> blockquote
> xzcat ubuntu-18.04-4.16.0-v7-desktop-odroid-u2-u3-20190308_shrink.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdd

This worked fine. The Odroid booted up and all was smooth.

But after that the microSD card seemed to have only 8GB of space. (Because of the image ?)
So I tried to expand it. So I opened it in GParted but was not able to see 32GB of free space nor even format it to the original size. :( No chance. It suddenly had only 8 GB of space all togerther.

Only "disks" seemed to at least see the original (full) capacity of this micrSD card. But was not able to format it nor resize it nor delete it ... :((

In the end I had to use EaseUS Partition Master (freeware) (??? OMG) in a virtual machine to get this SDCard fomatted to the original size. What a shame. :(